# Are authors able to approve a suggested edit for their own post, or is this a bug?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I was looking to the history of the approved suggested edits, and I found [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5381), on *Drupal Answers*. The suggested edit has been approved only by the author or the post.

[image: screenshot]

Is it what supposed to happen, or is it a bug? Suggested edits require at least two users to approve them, in all the Stack Exchange sites; only on *Stack Overflow*, a suggested edit is approved by three users.

Does it depend on the fact there were two suggested edits for the same post? [The other one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5375) had been approved 4 minutes before, by the author and another user.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: First one should have been rejected as to minor by the way.

Comment: Why would that be a bug? If the OP can change their post any which way they see fit, why would further approval of a suggested edit be required?

Comment: @Mat is correct: post author has the final vote, same "power" like moderator has over all posts.

Comment: @Mat That doesn't say the owner of a post can approve alone a suggested edit. Suggested edits need to be approved by at least two users.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That's not mentioned in the linked answer at all.

Comment: @Bolt and kiamlaluno: I'm sure that's the case as I've seen it several times before on Stack Overflow. Let me search..

Comment: But yes, post authors can vote to approve or reject edits to their posts. In fact, when an edit is suggested on one of your posts, you will receive a notification asking you to review it.

Comment: Couldn't find any official documentation for this.. @Bolt can you find such?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Not for the part where post authors get binding votes.

Comment: @Bolt so you think there is a chance this is ancient bug that was never hunted down?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Don't know...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn "Exception to above: if a vote is from the post author, the edit is accepted or rejected immediately."

Comment: @Bolt hmm.. I would re-open this then and wait for a dev to pop by and shed some light over this. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd See my previous comment. The answer for the duplicated question clearly says that.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It also says that it only applies to Stack Overflow, unless that has changed and applies to all sites now that all sites require at least two votes. This is all very confusing.

Comment: The answer to the linked question clearly states that the author of the post can instantly accept/reject a suggested edit. This is independent of the number of votes required.

Comment: @ChrisF That is written as exception for Stack Overflow. The exception could be just for the fact Stack Overflow required two users to accept/decline a suggested edit.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - YES! Now that all sites require two votes it will apply to all sites. Go and find a post of mine on a site where you don't have 2K and suggest an edit. I'll reject the edit and see if it disappears straight away